# Find the indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{3\sin x + \sin^3 x }$ with respect to x

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

The required integral is:

$\int \frac{1}{3\sin x + \sin^3 x }$ $dx$

I tried integrating this in many ways but never got the answer.

Showing all the approaches will be pointless as there are several (converting into other trigonometric functions, substitution,etc.).

After putting in so much effort and time, I concluded that this can't be solved by me.

I will be grateful if someone helped me out.

Comment: Showing what you have tried has the added benefit of also preventing the helpers on this site from wasting their time on fruitless approaches as well. That is, even if it didn’t go anywhere, you should show exactly what you have tried.

Comment: @Clayton Okay thanks for telling me.  I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\int \frac{1}{3\sin x + \sin^3 x }\ dx=\int \frac{\sin x}{3\sin^2x + \sin^4x}\ dx=\int \frac{\sin x}{3(1-\cos^2x) + (1-\cos^2x)^2}\ dx$$
now let substitution $\cos x=u$.

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int\frac{dx}{3\sin(x)+\sin^3(x)}$$
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{\sin(x)(3+\sin^2(x))}$$
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{\sin(x)(4-\cos^2(x))}$$
$$I=-\int\frac{dx}{\sin(x)(\cos^2(x)-4)}$$
$$I=-\int\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)(\cos^2(x)-4)}dx$$
$$I=\int\frac{\sin(x)}{(\cos^2(x)-1)(\cos^2(x)-4)}dx$$
Substitution: $u=\cos(x)$. Then $du=\sin(x)dx$. 
$$I=\int\frac{du}{(u^2-1)(u^2-4)}$$
$$I=\int\frac{du}{(u+1)(u-1)(u+4)(u-4)}$$
With a partial fraction decomposition,
$$I=\int\biggr(-\frac1{12(u+2)}+\frac1{6(u+1)}-\frac1{6(u-1)}-\frac1{12(u-2)}\biggl)du$$
$$I=-\frac1{12}\int\frac{du}{u+2}+\frac1{6}\int\frac{du}{u+1}-\frac1{6}\int\frac{du}{u-1}-\frac1{12}\int\frac{du}{u-2}$$
$$I=-\frac1{12}\ln|u+2|+\frac1{6}\ln|u+1|-\frac1{6}\ln|u-1|-\frac1{12}\ln|u-2|+C$$
$$I=-\frac1{12}\ln|\cos(x)+2|+\frac1{6}\ln|\cos(x)+1|-\frac1{6}\ln|\cos(x)-1|-\frac1{12}\ln|\cos(x)-2|+C$$
$$I=-\frac1{12}\ln|\cos^2(x)-4|+\frac1{6}\ln\bigg|\frac{\cos(x)+1}{\cos(x)-1}\bigg|+C$$
and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\frac{1}{3\sin(x)+\sin^3(x)}dx$$
let $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ and we obtain:
$$I=2\int\frac{1}{3\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^3}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=2\int\frac{1}{6t+\frac{(2t)^3}{(1+t^2)^2}}dt=2\int\frac{(1+t^2)^2}{6t(1+t^2)^2+8t^3}dt$$
This is an alternative way of doing it and note that $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ works for most functions involving the reciprocal of some trig function